# How to create a 'p' tag using css

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create an inline style that will act the same as a `<p>` tag. I have perused the http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ but I can't seem to find the goods. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What specifically do you want it to do? What's wrong with using a `p` tag?

Comment: Why not just use a `<p>` tag then? If you want something to act like a P tag, then use a P tag. don't take something else, say, `<i>` and force to act like something else.

Comment: What has the <p> tag so special that you can't style?

Comment: Use a `<DIV>` for goodness' sake and give it some top and bottom padding.... bingo, you have a <p> tag. And, from now on, when you're searching for GOOD information, start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

Comment: @DevlshOne You're implying that the W3 spec is bad. That's not necessarily true. I do agree that MDN would be a better resource for this, but why isn't the information from the W3 specs good?

Comment: @Doorknob http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @DevlshOne W3C `!==` W3Schools.

Comment: @Doorknob This conversation != worth it

Comment: @DevlshOne Okay, this is just terrible. W3C is the *official* speicification. W3Schools is a terrible website. W3C has **absolutely nothing to do** with W3Schools. You should actually know what you're talking about before posting a link just because it has "W3" in its name.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. `<p>` tags are inline. What do you mean by an "inline style"? If you want something to be inline why not just make it `display:inline;`?

Comment: @DevlshOne The site you linked to *specifically says* that W3C has nothing to do with w3schools.

Comment: It is certainly true that you should use <P> if you need it, however which element do you want to behave as the default <p> in the browser you're using? I think it is pretty valid to see a default and want to replicate the same display using css instead of using the element itself to decorate (like trying to use h1, h2 because "they're already big fonts")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dev tool (like the one in chrome) and see the properties for a `<p></p>`, however if you're just going to use it as a `<p>..` you must just use it. If you want to add few things then you can create a class that affects your `<p ..>`

Remember that HTML is content meaning and not meant for display, assume your tags will have the very same look, like if you open them in a plain text editor. It is valid that you want something to look like the **DEFAULT** in certain browser for a particular element, in this case `<p>`

This is how I scan defaults using chrome:

[image: <p> CSS]

Comment: @JasonTaylor: I have no idea what you were referring to in this answer, but do try to be nice, please.